# Too many for-loops and conditional operators

Tags: java

Not please with this outcome, function works as is, but would love to simplify and prettify it. Use of one for-loop would be great and limit the use of the conditional operator.

```
private void checkForOverage(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    Long sumOfAllocatedSize = 0L;
    Long sumOfLogicalSize = 0L;
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        // initially all records are set to GoogleTrackingState.UNPROCESSED
        if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE) {
            sumOfAllocatedSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        } else if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
            sumOfLogicalSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        }
    }

    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (sumOfAllocatedSize >= sumOfLogicalSize && record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        } else if (sumOfLogicalSize > sumOfAllocatedSize && record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE) {
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1

Comment: You should really add more context so that we can give you proper advice. What class does this method appear in, and what does the code for the `GoogleUsageMapping` class look like? See [ask]. (Our rules allow adding code for contextual information, but not revising the code that you have already posted.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have not done so. I recommend picking up the book [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) by Martin Fowler. It is an excellent book on exactly this topic.

One thing you can start with is to split the method by extracting each operation into a separate method. So that instead of doing everything at once you end up with a method per operation.

Doing so will let you examine what your code is actually doing and helps you see the patterns. Something like this:

```
private void checkForOverage(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    long allocatedSize = sumAllocated(records);
    long logicalSize = sumLogical(records);
    checkAllocated(records,allocatedSize, logicalSize);
    checkLogical(records,allocatedSize, logicalSize);
}

private long sumAllocated(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    long sumOfAllocatedSize = 0L;
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE) {
            sumOfAllocatedSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        }
    }
    return sumOfAllocatedSize;
}

private long sumLogical(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    long sumOfLogicalSize = 0L;
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
            sumOfLogicalSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        }
    }
    return sumOfLogicalSize;
}

private void checkAllocated(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records, long allocatedSize, long logicalSize) {
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (allocatedSize >= logicalSize && record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}

private void checkLogical(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records, long allocatedSize, long logicalSize) {
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (logicalSize > allocatedSize && record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE) {
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see both pairs of methods are nearly identical. All you have to do to unify them is to extract the difference as parameter.

```
private void checkForOverage(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    long allocatedSize = sumByType(records, MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE);
    long logicalSize = sumByType(records, MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE);
    check(records, allocatedSize >= logicalSize, MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE);
    check(records, logicalSize > allocatedSize, MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE);
}

private long sumByType(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records, MeasuredType type) {
    long sumOfAllocatedSize = 0L;
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == type) {
            sumOfAllocatedSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        }
    }
    return sumOfAllocatedSize;
}

private void check(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records, boolean condition, MeasuredType type) {
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (condition && record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == type) {
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely less efficient. At the very least I would move the condition check in `check` outside of the loop, if the condition is false, nothing needs to be done at all.

Comment: @konijn Sure. Minor optimizations can be done all over the place, but that was not the point of this example.

Comment: The difference is substantial for large data volumes.

Comment: thank you both for you contribution, very helpful, please see my newest editing, where I'm at a solution that I really like.

Answer (score 1):

After around of iterations I have come up with this solution, and I'm pretty please with it.
I had introduced a static class as a some kind of data container for **min**, **max** and **MeasuredType** variables, but when completed with that iteration I saw clearly that code could be more simplified.
So by abstracting code to more functions lead me to my final solution.

```
private void checkForOverage(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    MeasuredType measuredType = sumByMeasuredType(records);
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == measuredType) {
            record.setState(GoogleTrackingState.IGNORED_OVERAGE);
        }
    }
}

private MeasuredType sumByMeasuredType(List<GoogleUsageMapping> records) {
    long allocatedSize = 0L;
    long logicalSize = 0L;
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : records) {
        if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE) {
            allocatedSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        } else if (record.getUsage().getMeasuredType() == MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE) {
            logicalSize += record.getUsage().getQuantity().longValue();
        }
    }
    return (allocatedSize >= logicalSize) ? MeasuredType.LOGICAL_SIZE : MeasuredType.ALLOCATED_SIZE;
}
```